# JavaScript & jQuery; how to do snapping drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am looking for advice from all you wonderful people on the best way to do snapping drag and drop.

As part of a simple board game I am currently coding in JS (using jQuery for effects) users should be able to drag tiles from a dock onto a grid.

How does one complete the following objectives (preferably using jQuery).

> 1. Enable drag and drop onto the grid
> 2. Ensure during drag and drop items snap to each square of the grid
> 3. If the tile is placed completely off the grid, return to original place (dock)
> 4. If the tile is over the grid (at this point snapped), return current x & y to a function
> 5. Make any tiles being dragged slightly transparent, and go full color once in place or returned to dock

Sorry to ask such a big question, I just can't find any accurate advice online that would be me achieve this!

Many thanks,

**Edit: THE ANSWERS**
1&2 are solved by "draggable": http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable
3 is solved by "droppable" http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable
4 is solved by the above to validate and then `$(this).position.left` && `$(this).position.top`
5 is solved by a simple `$(this).css({opacity:0.5})` inside start on drag and the opposite on finish drag

Simples!

Comment: Have you looked at http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: This should probably be split into separate questions.  Some involve jQuery plugins, some game mechanics, and some display/graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you, this is for Drag & Drop with snap in jQuery

```
var snap = 10; /* the value of the snap in pixels */
var l,t,xInit,yInit,x,y;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY;
  drag(snap);
});

$('#obj').mousedown(function(e){
  l=$('#obj').position().left;
  t=$('#obj').position().top;
  xInit = e.pageX;
  yInit = e.pageY;
})


function drag(snap){
    w=$('#obj').width();
    h=$('#obj').height();
    var left = l+x-xInit;
    var top = t+y-yInit;
  if(!snap==0){
    left = (left/snap).toFixed()*snap;
    top = (top/snap).toFixed()*snap;
    $('#obj').css('left',left);
    $('#obj').css('top',top);
  }else{
    $('#obj').css('left',left);
    $('#obj').css('top',top);
  }
}
```