# Drag And Drop panels in a web page using JavaScript, CSS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to drag 2 panels in a page. I am able to drag 2 panels "FirstName" and "SecondName". but my requirement is I need to drag one panel above another. When I drag one panel to other end the panel I dragged back ground must be in white. I figured out something by looking at some tutorials, but I couldn't find the solution. Please help me if anyone knows the solution.

My JavaScript code is

```
Element.prototype.addClassName = function(name) {
  if (!this.hasClassName(name)) {
    this.className = this.className ? [this.className, name].join(' ') : name;
  }
};

Element.prototype.removeClassName = function(name) {
  if (this.hasClassName(name)) {
    var c = this.className;
    this.className = c.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + name + "(?:\\s+|$)", "g"), "");
  }
};


var samples = samples || {};




// Almost final example
(function() {
  var id_ = 'columns-almostFinal';
  var cols_ = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id_ + ' .column');
  var dragSrcEl_ = null;

  this.handleDragStart = function(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);

    dragSrcEl_ = this;

    this.style.opacity = '0.8';

    // this/e.target is the source node.
    this.addClassName('moving');
  };

  this.handleDragOver = function(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Allows us to drop.
    }

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

    return false;
  };

  this.handleDragEnter = function(e) {
    this.addClassName('over');
  };

  this.handleDragLeave = function(e) {
    // this/e.target is previous target element.

    this.removeClassName('over');
  };

  this.handleDrop = function(e) {
    // this/e.target is current target element.

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
    }

    // Don't do anything if we're dropping on the same column we're dragging.
    if (dragSrcEl_ != this) {
      dragSrcEl_.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
      this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }

    return false;
  };

  this.handleDragEnd = function(e) {
    // this/e.target is the source node.
    this.style.opacity = '1';

    [].forEach.call(cols_, function (col) {
      col.removeClassName('over');
      col.removeClassName('moving');
    });
  };

  [].forEach.call(cols_, function (col) {
    col.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');  // Enable columns to be draggable.
    col.addEventListener('dragstart', this.handleDragStart, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragenter', this.handleDragEnter, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragleave', this.handleDragLeave, false);
    col.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragend', this.handleDragEnd, false);
  });
})();
```

HTML code is this

```
</head>
<body onload="" style="background-color: #333333;">
<div id="PodTemplate">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="header_align">
                <ul class="inline">
                    <li>
                        <span style="float:left;clear:left;text-align:Right; ">First Name</span>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <span   style="float:right;">
                            <div><a href=" #" ><img src="images/maximize_up.png"></a><div>
                        </span>
                    </li>

                    <li>    
                        <span style="float:right;">
                        <div> <a href="#">
                                 <img src="images/Forward.JPG" onClick="dropdown()"/></a> 
                                    <div class="drop" id="hide" style="display:none">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><img src="images/excel_icon.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/xml_file.png"></li></br>
                                            <li><img src="images/xml_file.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/excel_icon.png"></li>
                                     </ul>
                                   </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>   

                    <li>
                        <span style="float:right;">
                                <div><a href=" #"><img src="images/minimize_up.png"></a>

                                </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
         </Div>
         </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="header_align">
                <ul class="inline">
                    <li>
                        <span style="float:left;clear:left;text-align:Right; ">Second Name</span>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <span   style="float:right;">
                            <div><a href=" #" ><img src="images/maximize_up.png"></a><div>
                        </span>
                    </li>

                    <li>    
                        <span style="float:right;">
                        <div> <a href="#">
                                 <img src="images/Forward.JPG" onClick="dropdown()"/></a> 
                                    <div class="drop" id="hide" style="display:none">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><img src="images/excel_icon.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/xml_file.png"></li></br>
                                            <li><img src="images/xml_file.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/excel_icon.png"></li>
                                     </ul>
                                   </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>   

                    <li>
                        <span style="float:right;">
                                <div><a href=" #"><img src="images/minimize_up.png"></a>

                                </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
         </Div>
    </div>

  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="drag with effect.js"></script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
[draggable] {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
dd {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.column {
display:inline;
  height: 500px;
  width: 650px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #1C1C1C;
  background-color: #000000;   /*Body colour*/
  /*margin-right: 5px;*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px; /*Describes about box border(shape of the Box curve)*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: default;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.column header_align {
   box-shadow: 3px;
  padding: 3px; /*upper line */
 /* background: -moz-linear-gradient(left center, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21)); */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,
                               color-stop(0, rgb(0,0,0)),
                               color-stop(0.50, rgb(79,79,79)),
                               color-stop(1, rgb(21,21,21)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left center, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21));
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left center, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left center, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21));
 /* border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; */
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -o-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -o-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
#PodTemplate .column {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.2s ease-out;
}
#PodTemplate .column.over
 {
  border: 2px dashed #000;
}
#PodTemplate .column.moving {
  opacity: 0.25;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
  -o-transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here.  You can see different demos.  You will have to mix and match, but basically using jquery droppable you can set docking areas for draggable items and set them to snap to location.  [JavaScript & jQuery; how to do snapping drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973407/javascript-jquery-how-to-do-snapping-drag-and-drop)

Comment: But i want it in Javascript,css3 and html

Comment: Hi, i want only in JAvascript and css3 , i dont want it in jquery

Comment: @Swaroop - jQuery is JavaScript. It's a framework that will save you from reinventing the wheel (such as your "addClassName" and "removeClassName" functions). I highly recommend taking a look at it, as it will save you countless time and headaches.

Comment: Ok, So can You please refer me any tutorials, For dragging and drooping 2 panels each other in a layout. Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is redundant code for that. I don't want additional frameworks too . All can be done with Html/css/javaScript without jQuery. Cheers Swaroop !